# What is the proper word for 'lookuped'

Tags: word-request

I'm a computer programmer trying to be perfect in my function and data type names. I have a function called "LookupAccountName" and want to create a name for the data structure with results of that function. So I came up with something like "LookupedAccount"

This sounds ugly to me. Google also doesn't find too much occurrences of this word, which is a sign that native language speakers don't use it.

What options do I have for naming something that was created as a result of a lookup? Is it "lookuped" or "looked up" or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Variable names in computer programs are not necessarily subject to the rules that natural language follows. But LookedUp is the word you want, not Lookuped.  The "up" is detached from the verb stem. To look something up.  I looked her number up when I got to town. The number was looked up.

Comment: I would expect a function named "LookupAccountName" to return an object of type "AccountName".  You might name an individual variable "lookedupAccount", but you wouldn't use that name for the data structure itself.

Comment: @Hellion, makes sense, but unfortunately in Windows API LookupAccountName actually means "Lookup Account details by its Name", so it takes a name and returns account properties (SID and some other details that don't make a good abstraction together). That's why I chosen LookedUpAccount.

Comment: "Lookup" looks weird to me as a verb; the standard way to write it that I've seen is "look up" (a "lookup" is a kind of query or service, but the verb is "look up", just like you "log in" on a "login page"). I would honestly expect "LookupAccountName" to be the name of an account used to look things up: the name of a lookup account. The function name would be `LookUpAccountName`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is listed as explicitly off-topic in the [help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a computer program, where consistency of naming is more important that smooth language, I'd say "LookedUpName", or maybe "LookupNameResult".

In common speech, I'd probably say, "found name". As in, "You said to look up the name. The name found was 'Sally Jones'."

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `lookup` as synonymous to `find`, then use `find`.

`Lookup` already has a specific meaning in another context, as a [Lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), which is a noun.

I would argue that `lookup` should never be at the start of a function name. The separable verb `to look something up` would mean that it would require camel-case, ie. `lookUpAccountName`.

I could imagine it as a noun however, e.g. `accountNameLookup`, which I would expect to be some sort of hash table.

`lookedUpName` seems redundant. `foundName` as a variable also seems potentially misleading in a programming context, as depending on your implementation, if it *wasn't* found, then it could contain null, false, empty or whatever.

Just use `account` and make sure that it *is* there, through whatever language constructs are available.